# In MongoDB, why would this aggregate() query and this find() query return different results?

Tags: database, mongodb

In MongoDB, why would this aggregate() query and this find() query return different results?

They both return a different set of 20 results, with a few results in common.

#### Aggregate

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: {
                      type: "Point",
                      coordinates: [
          -79.3927217,
          43.648358
        ],
      },
                    distanceField: "distance",
                    minDistance: 0,
                    maxDistance: 100000,
                    spherical: true,
    },
  },
  {
                $match: {
                  date: {
                    $gt: 1529825292207,
                    $lt: 1659425292207,
      }
    },
  },
  {
                $project: {
                    id: 1,
                    distance: 1,
                    _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
                $sort: {date: -1
    }
  },
  {
                $limit: 20
  }
])
```

#### Find

```
db.items.find({
  "loc": {
    "$nearSphere": {
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -79.3927217,
          43.648358
        ]
      },
      "$minDistance": 0,
      "$maxDistance": 100000
    }
  },
  "date": {
              $gt: 1529825292207,
              $lt: 1659425292207,
  },
},
{

  id: 1,
  _id: 0,
  distance: 1
}
).sort({date: -1
}).limit(20)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the aggregation pipeline, you are sorting after projecting out the find you are trying to sort, so at the point the `$sort` stage processes, none of the documents have a `date` field, so that stage doesn't change the order of the documents in the stream.

If you reorder the pipeline to put the $sort stage ahead of the $project stage, it should return the same result as the find.